# Checking for secure network in C#

Tags: c#

I have an application that uploads sensitive information over the network. The information is encrypted, but I do not want the data to be uploaded over non-secured, or WEP secured wireless networks. How can I check for this?

Answer (score 1):

Disallowing information from being transferred over non-secured networks should be done at the network level, not the application level.

A simple example would be to block ports which aren't secure and enable IPSec or SSL.

Comment: I don't have that option available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all sure how to do this or if it's even possible so the below are just some suggestions for things you might be able to look at.

You might be able to get out some info via WMI, maybe using the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` class as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28VS.85%29.aspx). Just be aware that my understanding is that some network adapter drivers use the wrong details (so a wireless card might say that it's a normal network adapter or something) so even if you can get out the information from there I'm not sure how reliable it would be.

Another possible option that I can think of is if you can look up which the current network connection is and then look at the properties of it which you should be able to do using the [Network Configuration Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559080%28VS.85%29.aspx).